# work with Promise.then.then... or async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Which one is better? There is a design pattern of which one should I use (considering a react environment)?

Let's use as example those following blocks of code:

```js
function exampleFunction(data) {
  return doSomeStuff(data)
    .then((firstResponse) => doOtherStuff(firstResponse))
    .then(() => moreStuff(data))
    .then((finalData) => finalData);
}
```

and

```js
async function secondExampleFunction(data) {
  const firstResponse = await doSomeStuff(data);
  await doOtherStuff(firstResponse);
  return await moreStuff(data);
}
```

The first one seems to separate the features better, but it's hard to read, while the second function is cleaner but seems to be harder to deeply understand what is going on.

Comment: `async`/`await` is based on Promise objects too; they basically do the same thing.

Comment: What await does actually is it just waits on the line until it gets the response in your case it waits until it gets the doSomeStuff response and then moves on to the next line.
The 2nd one is better and it does the same thing as the first one. In the 2nd case you are missing the error handling thing which you can do by adding simple try/catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async/await`, just gives you the functionality to write the async code written with promises in a more synchronous manner.

I personally like `async/await`, because the code is much cleaner and readable.

---

**Error Handling** is different in both of them

With `.then` style pattern you need to use `.catch` for error handling

```js
function exampleFunction(data) {
  return doSomeStuff(data)
    .then((firstResponse) => doOtherStuff(firstResponse))
    .then(() => moreStuff(data))
    .then((finalData) => finalData);
    .catch(e => /* error handling code */)
}
```

but with `async/await` you can use traditional `try/catch` block.

```js
async function secondExampleFunction(data) {
  try {
    const firstResponse = await doSomeStuff(data);
    await doOtherStuff(firstResponse);
    return moreStuff(data); // notice no `await`
  }
  catch(e) {
    // error handling code
  }
}
```

One more thing, in async/await pattern you don't need to put `await` when you are returning a promise from `async` method.

---

**Scopes** is different in both of them

With `.then` style pattern, your callback method is the scope for variables but with `async/await` pattern the whole method's scope is available.

---

**Note:** One more thing I have experienced is writing a recursion code with `async/await` is way easier than writing one with promises.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO async/await is the more modern and readable way. However you can mix both ways if it improves readability.

The biggest benefit from the technical side - IMHO - is that you can use try.. catch. Think of what would happen if an exception occurs somewhere in the first example in contrast to following modification of your example:

```
async function secondExampleFunction(data) {

   try {
        const response = await doSomeStuff(data)
           .then(data2=>doOtherStuff(fr))
           .then(data3=>doMoreStuff(data));
       return response;
   } catch (ex) {
       return Promise.resolve("error")
   }
}
```

### --

Also in your first example - let's assume exampleFunction gets called twice very fast. What value will data have in line 3 the when the second call hits?

All in all - again - async/await is more modern meaning safer and more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
There is any javascript/reactjs design pattern for it, i mean, chose one of them?

Comment: pattern for what?